# Magento caching error

Tags: javascript, magento, merge, http-status-code-404

I'm looking for a solution to a strange problem I stumbled upon this afternoon.

My category pages began throwing a 404 not found error for a media/js file (one of the Magento-generated merged js files, I believe). Naturally this has caused the category pages to malfunction in a few places, including placing an unexplained number at the top of the page and breaking the nav. Here it is in action: http://www.vapetropolis.ca/herb-grinders.

I've tried disabling js and css merging in the backend. I've also tried flushing magento cache, flushing cache storage, flushing the javascript/css cache, as well as manually deleting all entries within var/cache. After all this flushing, the media/js directory is empty. However, the category pages are still looking for this same file (all other pages are still working fine).

Notably, the identical site on my local machine is working fine, and includes the file not found by the production site.

**Edit**: throwing the js file from the local to production site hasn't helped - there are multiple js errors thrown on the category pages still.

I'm guessing this problem has something to do with Magento's messed up merge functionality.

**Edit(2)**: Problem has to do with caching (thank you [runamok](/users/699493/runamok)). When a querystring is added to the URL, the page works fine. So it must be that magento's caching is serving up a faulty page somehow.

I've tried disabling all cache, as well as disabling precompiling on the backend, but behaviour remains the same

**Edit(3)**: Still in need of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may have fixed the issue based on this url existing.
http://www.vapetropolis.ca/media/js/a87bf7cc5dcd7a07e58a41c1063e1f4a.js

Generally speaking this is because the permissions for the media/js file are not correct.
Obviously chmod 777 is the easiest way to set this but ideally you should just make sure the directory is owned by the user running apache.

Furthermore if you are using some sort of full page cache you will likely need to flush that too. The pages expect that the file is already there so it will not attempt to regenerate it.

Finally are you using any sort of service like cloudflare or varnish or a cdn or anything else that may cache the 404 for a short time?

Comment: Actually I can tell that you are using some sort of caching by seeing how fast pages are served. If I add a random attribute to the querystring it goes from taking 200 milliseconds to 2.5 seconds. When I change the url like so: view-source:http://www.vapetropolis.ca/handheld-portable-vaporizers?dir=desc&no_cache=&order=position then your config changes take effect and the javascript is not being merged any longer...

Comment: Yes! When I add the querystring, the errors go away and the page works properly. But I can't figure out where the caching problem is...I've disabled all cache in the backend, and disabled precompiling but the errors still exist

Comment: I  still maintain it's some sort of caching extension. Is the store hosted by someone else or did you set up the server stack or what? From what I can see you are using nginx on port 80 in front of apache at port 8080. Did you set up all extensions or did someone else? 

I would suggest going to docroot/app/code/local and docroot/app/code/community and running this command:
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d

Then do some research on those extensions... I am thinking maybe you are running something like lightspeed by tinybrick.
Can you add "bad" and "good" url examples please?